# Android emulator and maps

Tags: android, maps, emulation

I am developing my app with android maps. It works well in a real device but I cannot get to work in the Android emulator.
I created an Android Virtual Device (AVD) using this settings:

```
Device: Galaxy Nexus
Google Apis level 19 (KitKat)
1024 Ram, Internal storage 200Mb, sdcard 50Mb.
```

I have Google Play Services installed.
I have also installed the Google Maps app and it works (slowly, very slowly, but it works)

But when I open the map with my app it displays the zoom in/out buttons (+-) and the logo "google" but the map is not displayed. It even reacts to events like long pressing on it but there is not map with roads or anything. Let me paste a picture:
[image]

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: does log cat is showing anything

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, it says "Failed to load map. Error contacting Google Servers. This is probably an authentication issue". And by the way, it works when installed in a real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like the problem was with the Release key and the Debug key.
I found this [webpage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information). There you can read about Debug certificate.

I have solved myself installing the real apk on the emulator using this command line:

```
C:\MySdkFolder\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe install "C:\MyApps\MyApp.apk"
```

And now it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

If the same app is working on a real device, it could be an issue with the API image you used for AVD device (Google Apis level 19 (KitKat)). I would suggest trying with older API version (Google APIs image). Another suggestion is to give it a try with x86 Google APIs image. [Here is a detailed article on how to use it with Google Maps](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/how-to-use-the-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm-android-emulator).

Comment: can you open browser on emulator and make sure it can access the web. you mentioned google maps works but very slowly. It could be that your app is timing out on emulator, if everything else seems ok.

Comment: Yes, browser works ok. I don't understand why it is so complicated and why there are so many tricky things to make this work

Comment: android emulator with google apis can be tricky. I suggest you try out one of the google maps sample apps, to rule out emulator itself is not the problem.